# Passing an object by reference and storing it as a member variable

Tags: c++, class, pass-by-reference

I can't figure out how to make "a" be the same object as "b".

Gamestate.h :

```
class GameState {
public: 
  void init(A& b);

protected:
  static A a;
}
```

Gamestate.cpp :

```
A GameState::a;

void GameState::init(A& b)
    {
        ???
    }
```

I could use pointers like this :

Gamestate.h :

```
class GameState {
public: 
  void init(A* b);

protected:
  static A* a;
}
```

Gamestate.cpp :

```
A* GameState::a;

void GameState::init(A* b)
        {
            a = b;
        }
```

But I would prefer a to be the same object and not a pointer to the object so that I don't have to dereference it when I want to access "a".

Comment: Use `std::move` to move the passed object over to your member variable.

Comment: You can't make it the same object, by definition `GameState::a` is it's own object. You can make it an object with the same value with simply `a = b;` but it seems you don't want that.

Comment: @schorsch312: He want to use a reference and not destroy the original object by moving it. std::move is only a cast, so also some more code is necessary to get it really moved into its own object. But as said: It was not the question to move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. The simple reason is that `GameState::a` and the object passed by reference to `GameState::init` are distinct objects, they will never be the same.

Now, let's talk about ways to fix this in an "idiomatic C++" way:

Firstly, think about what `GameState::init()` means. It is a call on an instance of class `GameState`, which only writes to a `static` class property. Why doesn't it write to the instance's property? This smells a bit as if `GameState::a` was effectively a global variable, which inherits all its badness.

As a different approach, pass dependencies (like the parameter to `init()`) into the constructor (a.k.a. "Dependency Injection"). Then, you can initialize a reference to that parameter with the injected dependency:

```
class GameState {
    public:
    GameState(A& a): m_a(a) {}

    private:
    A& m_a;
};
```

Note that you must make sure that the `A` instance outlives the `GameState` instance. In some cases, where you have to dynamically allocate things and where you don't need them outside any more, passing ownership via a smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr`) is desirable, you can then replace the reference with such a smart pointer.

Comment: I wanted GameState::a to be accessible by every game state that inherits from GameState. I had no idea how to do that so I tried making it a static member variable of the class. There probably is some better way to do this.
I don't know what dependency injection is but I'll look it up and try to understand. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: If `m_a` was protected, it could be accessed from derived classes, too. `static` means "one per class" as opposed to "one per instance of the class".

Comment: GameState::a is actually an input manager and needs to be available for every gamestate and there has to be only one of them. That's why I used static and why it is protected.

Comment: The `GameState` class can probably operate regardless of how many input managers exist, so I wouldn't code this there. In any case, if you decide that this is a `static` class property, then the initialization function which sets that property should also be `static`. However, you will not be able to use a reference there then. Probably using a smart pointer would be the way to go.